# Spring as standalone or on Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am seeking for the advantages of having Spring deployed on Tomcat rather then have it out side of any application server container.

My project doesn't require any web support. 
It does requires technologies like transactions management, DB pool, JMX, low latency and more common java-ee technology.

So why would I use tomcat anyway? if it's just because of the reason of having DB POOL, I could implement it myself. I am looking for low latency solution.

Again, my project is a total backend no need of any web support.

So what do I miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you actually mean by "more common Java EE technology"?

If it's "just a back end", what is the *front* end? How will applications talk to the back end?

If there's no need for a web interface, there's no advantage to using a web container.

If you have complex transaction management needs, need message queues, etc. that may be easier to set up under an *application* server (as opposed to a web container) because there are existing admin/management interfaces. All those may *also* be set up on their own, but can be more of a pain--using Spring may mitigate that pain somewhat.

The need for "more common Java EE technology", however, makes me a little nervous about implementing a standalone app, though. App containers have all that "common Java EE technology" built-in, tested, and functional. If you're bolting a variety of packages together to give you "common Java EE technology", without using a common Java EE app container, it's likely easier to just use an app container, which also gives you the benefit of providing normalized access to your services from a variety of sources.

Comment: I am using app container today. but we want to move into Spring. so Why would I need Spring inside app container if all I need is the app container services?

Comment: I am not asking what is the purpose of app container or it's benefits. I do ask why do I need spring on it if Spring already implemented all those technologies

Comment: @rayman Because Spring *doesn't* implement all those technologies--Spring *wraps* those technologies in a unified way. It doesn't *implement* JPA, it has Hibernate and JPA helpers. You still need a JMS implementation, caching, whatever.

Comment: Yes.I understand that Spring doesnt have the implementations but only those templates. But so is Tomcat. if for example I chose HornetQ as jms implementation I will need to add it's jars to tomcat. so why couldnt I just add it's jars to standalone and achieve the same result? Still cant find the benefit of Tomcat except it's HTTP technologies.

Comment: @rayman As I said, of course you could build a complete stack of the technologies you need-but then you're building a complete stack of technologies you need. If you have the time and desire to do so, go right ahead (and test it, etc). I rarely have that luxury, and the system admins rarely have the time to learn a bunch of disparate admin tools (compared to having them in a single unified interface).

Comment: ofcourse I dont have the time to build stack of existence technologies. but this is all about. those technologies which I need already builed inside the Spring. so why would I need to have my Spring inside tomcat if that "stack" can be used also in Spring standalone?

Comment: @rayman I already told you the most typical reasons, and *specifically* said if there's no need for any web interaction, there *isn't* any reason--although a web interface is the easiest way to get system visibility. I don't know what else you want me to say, so I'm going to stop talking.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is not a web app, you can use any of the non-web specific application contexts listed under **All Known Implementing Classes** [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html). You can then init the context from a main method in a runnable jar.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need web support, you don't have to use tomcat or any other app server. Spring will provide you with most of the features you need. For connection pool, there are many options available such as c3p0 & apache dbcp. You can use one of them.

The only thing you have to worry about is a clean shutdown of your process. You can do that by implementing your own shutdown hook.

Comment: This is kind of answer I was looking for. so why many people using Spring inside jboss/tomcat although they dont need any web interface. What advantage does it give to them? why not to run the spring as stand alone.

Comment: Apart from web app & web services, app servers provide support for EJB/MDB's. That could be a very valid reason to use them. Also, if you already have an app server running, you may choose to deploy scheduled jobs etc on the same server to have a simple deployment architecture

Comment: But I have kind of "MDB" implementations within Spring. so why would I need the app container's MDB?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons to deploy the application in `tomcat` is that it will provide you all of the connection burden, thread management and so on. Nothing that you could not implement yourself. But bear in mind that `tomcat` is robust, and they already deal with all of the troubles of implement that logic.

Besides of that there is little point in use an application container (if you think that not having to develop and maintain that amount of code is easy).

Comment: Tomcat only does management of http connections and threads related to servlet/web/http processing. But the OP doesn't have a http interface

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use tomcat or anything else. Spring is container already. Init spring in one simple  thread, makes sure it has proper clean up flow. and that's all. I used to work on several server side integration application which do allot, communicate over different protocols to other server, and everything was easily done with out Web Containers or J2ee Application Servers. Spring have support for almost everything, sometimes with 3d party libs(caching, transactions, pools, etc ....) Simplified version could be like :

```
...
pubcic static  void main (String args[]){
 Server.server = new Server(...);
 server.initSpringContext()
 server.keepAlive();
 server.cleanupResources();
}

..
abstract class Server{

abstract void initSpring();
abstract void cleanUpResources();
abstract void shutdown(){
  this.state = STOP;
};
public void keepAlive()
 while(state!=STOP){
  sleep(1000)
 }

}
```

Comment: What about resources cleaning? Does Spring responsible for cleaning it's resources itself? Since I always used application servers I never had to pay attention for cleaning resources everything was pooled.

Comment: Same there. Depends on what kind of resource do you use. As example if you use JMS, u can use spring impl of jms Connection factory and it will provide you with pool. Same regarding jdbc or anything else. Spring much more light weight comparing to app.server since you don't need to turn on support of everything. However on other hand you need to configure everything manually.